# Obter valores de Input Text dentro de modal-body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-3, jquery-ui

Caros;

Como obter valores de INPUT TEXT e direciona-los para o Body-Modal?

Tenho um formulário com vários inputs desabilitados, para que o usuário não edite. Porem, ao clicar no botão que chama o MOdal, queria que no modal aparecesse os valores deste INPUT.

MODAL:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

FORM:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desculpem por postar a imagem, tentei colocar o código e não estáva indo formatado. Conto com a ajuda de vocês.

Grato.

Comment: Para adicionar código formatado basta colar o código, selecioná-lo por completo, e clicar no botão **{ }** acima do editor de texto, ou adicionar quatro espaços previamente antes de começar a escrever código.

Answer (score 1):

Caros;

Resolvi meu problema com o código abaixo:

```
function copy_form()
{
id('modalxxx').value = id('xxx').value;
id('modalyyy').value = id('yyy').value;
id('modalrrr').value = id('rrr').value;
id('modalttt').value = id('ttt').value;


}

function id( el ){
   return document.getElementById( el );
}
    window.onload = function()
    {
    id('btnenviar').onclick = function()
    }
    copy_form();
}
                 }

</script>
```

Agradeço pela ajuda :)

Answer (score 0):

Primeira coisa: A resposta que vou te dar é utilizando jQuery.

Para acessar o valor de um input field utilizando jQuery, tenha certeza que você setou um id para cada um deles. Depois, dentro do seu código javascript, acesse o valor da seguinte forma:

```
var input_value = $("seu_id").val();
```

Para adicionar estes valores no formulário, o ideal é que você, ao clicar em "Clique Aqui", recupere todos os valores dos input fields, e sete estes valores nos fields do seu formulário. Para isso, você deve definir blocos de texto no seu modal, cada um com um id. Supondo que você tenha um input field com o seu nome, e você deseja enviar ele para o modal. Supondo que seu modal tenha um paragráfo da seguinte forma:

```
<p id="nome_modal"></p>
```

E que no seu form você tenha um input field definido da seguinte forma:

```
<input type="text" id="nome disabled />
```

Utilizando jQuery, você fará:

```
var nome = $("nome").val();
$("#nome_modal").text(nome);
```